# Cookies between Laravel and PHPbb Applications

Tags: php, laravel, session, cookies, phpbb

I have two subdomains of the same domain:

- **laravelapp.domain** (Laravel 5.4 App)
- **phpbb.domain** (phpBB 3.2 App)

I have set a cookie in the Laravel App's middleware:

```
$cookie = cookie(
    'sessid',
    $session->token,
    \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(1)->toDateTimeString(),
    'domain',
    false,
    true
);
    
return $next($request)->cookie($cookie);
```

So I can verify the previous code is working when returning the value of `request()->cookie('sessid')` from the same app.

Until here everything is fine. I want to read the cookie "**sessid**" from the phpBB App and I am trying to accomplish it with this:

In the ucp.php file I write this:

```
var_dump(request_var($config['cookie_name'] . '_sessid', '', false, true));
```

I've also tried this, from the [wiki page](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Function.request_var#Example_.2310_Getting_variables_from_a_cookie):

```
var_dump(request_var('sessid', '', false, true));
```

But what I get is:

> string(0) ""

Also I saw that I am not able to use `$_COOKIE['sessid']` since it has been disabled for global purposes.

According to Web Developer extension for Mozilla I see the following cookie information:

> Name  sessid
>
> Value
>
> eyJpdiI6IlNmb2xjMmRTeEtScnNNTjhyNlwvZUN3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6InVDTFIrYXhxdjl0bHk3aXFxQ05RR0dQam9XRTcwZ2ZoVXQxTVkzZnZiTzJRWDlCNU5HR3RTXC9xY05yOUZucDJkTzkrc0dxdTJYZVp3WlN5blJ5ZmlxOWIxaWtSXC9Tam0waXJvK0FObW5FQXuiWDk0N0pQV1IxNnhaazlTdmFvb3NiRm54UjVjSXZGZ0hEM1JMN0txd3d3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiJiMGY0MTcyZjhhZjJmNWE0Y2IzZjNjMTMyOTIxOTdiYmM1NzMzNzBjMTExNmMxOGRkMGI4YTI0ZmFjOTYyODVmIn0%3D
>
> Host  domain
>
> Path  /
>
> Expires   Wed, 23 Aug 2017 10:47:22 GMT
>
> Secure    Yes
>
> HttpOnly  Yes

What should I do to achieve reading the cookie ***sessid*** in the phpBB application?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: first of all, have you checked the cookie already exists in the browser side?

Comment: Yes, added that Client Side information

Comment: ah right! i do forget, if i'm not wrong, laravel *always* encrypts the cookie it generated.. so, it is not a big question why the cookie can't be read by phpbb - because it does not know how to read it... and raw cookies are looked like [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie). your cookie dump might be seemingly meaningless, but it remind me things. then, the next thing to do is.. either using [raw cookie](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-non-encrypted-cookie), or teach phpbb how to read the cookie.

Comment: Actually I am seeing the same information about the cookie in the phpbb app, So I think encryption is not the issue here.

Comment: no, i mean.. uh perhaps i explained it rashly. basically a plain cookie will have its value(s) looked like: `field1:value1;field2:value2;..`, but Laravel encrypt the entire key-value pairs into a single string - hence you see in phpbb as is (the garbled text).